# Magento 2 - Where to put images to use in css

Tags: magento2, css, image, locations

What is the best location to put the images that I use in my custom css file? And what is the best way to get to the image from the css file?

The location of my custom css is:
app/design/frontend/theme/themename/web/css

I have Magento in developer mode.

Magento does something when deploying the files and I don't know if the location of css and image will change...

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep images in below path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/images

So the full path for image demo.jpg will be

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/images/demo.jpg

Your CSS file path for custom.css

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/css/custom.css

Now you can use that demo.jpg image in the custom.css file as below

```
.test{background: url('../images/demo.jpg');}
```

Now run the below commands

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 3):

You can use : `../images/some-image.png`.

1. Your css in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/css/stylename.css`.

   ```
   .div-name{
       background-image: url('../images/some-image.png');
   }
   ```
2. Your image in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/images/some-image.png`.
3. Deploy the static content. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`.

Answer (score 1):

The best location to put the images is (If using anywhere in theme):

app\design\frontend\theme\themename\web\images

And the best way to get image from the less file is :

background: url('@{baseDir}images/filename.png')no-repeat center center;

**Note:** The location of images will never change When you use '@{baseDir}'

Comment: Hi Chandra, I'm using a normal plain css file, I think @{baseDir} cannot be used in that?

Comment: @n00bly you can't use @{baseDir} in css files. Only less file. Because less files are compiled and create css files.